# how to get textbox contents from a webpage using its loaded source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How do i copy a dynamic text that is being generated in a textbox at a random webpage? i dont have any access to the code or the api's related to the webpage.

```
<div id="results">
          <span class="final" id="final_span">hello</span> <span class="interim" id="interim_span"></span>
        </div>
```

using chrome dev tools i can see the text displayed is "hello" in the webpage. how do i make a programatical copy of the same? and use it in my application?

```
document.getElementById("interim_span").innerHTML
```

will get me if i have to the source of the webpage. how do i do the same from a standalone js ?

PS: am new to JS.

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I dont understand you @j08691

Comment: You have two spans in your example with the same ID `id="interim_span"`. IDs must be unique.

Comment: edited the same. Was a copy paste error.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you mean by "how do I do the same from a standalone JS?"
Do you mean you'll be getting the source of this page from a separate page using JavaScript, AJAX style?

Comment: take this stackoverflow page as an example. when you type something in the above search bar, how do i get the data that i typed and use it in my application?

Comment: like `$(inputelement).val()`?

Comment: http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html i am trying to get the recognized speech from the above url to use it in my own application at run time. hope its clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the data from the webpage by making it to send it via web socket.